# plot is created in wrong gui window

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have a situation where I create a waitbar, read a large image and plot the image to the gui axes. However what happens is that the plot is created inside the waitbar instead.

```
hWait = waitbar(0,'1','Name','Reading calibration file ...');
% why do I need the '1' in waitbar ???

readCalibrationImage( handles );

% delete( hWait ); 
set(handles.figure1,'CurrentAxes',handles.axesROI)
plotROIImage( handles, imagedata, roi, lineV, lineH, doExportPlot )
```

only if I delete the handle the plot is created in the correct window.

How do I enfore plotting to the correct window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting a

```
set(0, 'CurrentFigure', handles.figure1);
```

in front of the `CurrentAxes` statement. AFAIK, `set(...,'CurrentAxes')` does not automatically switch the active figure...

Comment: I'm not sure what it's *really* called (and I don't have the time now to google for it, sorry...), but 0 in this context represents a handle to the system, environment variables, etc. Try doing `set(0)` and you'll see a list of available environment options.

Comment: @EitanT: tx, you're not too far off yourself :)